# Calculating feature vectors for image segments (super-pixels)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, classification, scikit-image

For tasks like clustering or classification on images we generally convert images to numerical feature vectors. Now, instead of calculating feature vectors for an entire image, I would like to generate features for segments of an image (not constrained to rectangular segments). For example, using the SLIC algorithm ([skimage.segmentation.slic](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic)) I can segment an image into super pixels. Now I would like to generate features (region size, location, color, shape and texture features) for each segment as described in section 5.3 of

> Gould, Stephen, et al. "Multi-class segmentation with relative location prior." International Journal of Computer Vision 80.3 (2008): 300-316.

Are there existing libraries in python that can help me generate those features, given an image and a mask of segments? Can I do this using skimage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any such library. However, I needed to compute features myself some time ago and you can find some code snippets below. Although, the code is not in Python, it might be helpful for you. Note that I experimented with supervoxels; therefore, you may find some PCL reference in there.

If you start implementing features yourself, have a look at the following publications for some ideas (in both cases Table 1):

```
Derek Hoiem, Andrew N. Stein, Alexei A. Efros, Martial Hebert:
Recovering Occlusion Boundaries from a Single Image. ICCV 2007: 1-8
Joseph Tighe, Svetlana Lazebnik:
Superparsing - Scalable Nonparametric Image Parsing with Superpixels. International Journal of Computer Vision 101(2): 329-349 (2013)
```

Note that not all definitions from the header file are actually implemented; however, they may serve as inspiration.

Header:

```
#ifndef SUPERPIXELFEATURES_H
#define SUPERPIXELFEATURES_H

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <string>

namespace features {

    /**
     * Class SuperpixelFeatures represents a set of features computed for
     * each superpixel in a given image.
     */
    class SuperpixelFeatures {

    public:

        /**
         * Construct superpixel features form only an image.
         * 
         * @param image
         * @param labels
         */
        SuperpixelFeatures(const cv::Mat &image, int** labels);

        /**
         * Construct superpixel features from the image and its depth and
         * a given superpixel segmentation.
         * 
         * @param image
         * @param depth
         * @param labels
         */
        SuperpixelFeatures(const cv::Mat &image, const cv::Mat &depth, int** labels);

        /**
         * Constructu superpixel features form the image and a point cloud and
         * a given superpixel segmentation.
         * 
         * @param image
         * @param pointCloud
         */
        SuperpixelFeatures(const cv::Mat &image, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud, int** labels);

        /**
         * Destructor.
         */
        ~SuperpixelFeatures();

        /**
         * Add maximum color in each channel to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addMaximumColor();

        /**
         * Add minimum color in each channel to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addMinimumColor();

        /**
         * Add mean color to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addMeanBGRColor();

        /**
         * Add mean position to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addMean3DPosition();

        /**
         * Add mean position (pixel coordinates) to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addMean2DPosition();

        /**
         * Add the surface normal (mean normal) to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addMeanNormal();

        /**
         * Add a 3D bounding box of the superpixel to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addBoundingBox();

        /**
         * Add the compactness of the superpixel in its 2D sens to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addCompactness();

        /**
         * Add the area in pixels to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addArea();

        /**
         * Add the color covariance matrix to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addColorCovariance();

        /**
         * Add the position covariance matrix to the features.
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addPositionCovariance();

        /**
         * Add point-ness, curve-ness and surface-ness to the features.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addSuperpixelStatistics();

        /**
         * Add a color histogram of the given number of bins to the features.
         * 
         * @param bins
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addColorHistogram(int bins);

        /**
         * Add the ground truth label to the features.
         * 
         * @param labels
         * @return 
         */
        Eigen::Vector2i addGroundTruth(int** labels);

        /**
         * Get the dimension of the computed features.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        int getFeatureDimension() const;

        /**
         * Get the total number of superpixels.
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        int getNumberOfSuperpixels() const;

        /**
         * Get pointer to comptued features.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        Eigen::MatrixXd* getFeatures() const;

    protected:

        void appendFeatures(Eigen::MatrixXd features);

        cv::Mat* image;
        int height;
        int width;

        int** labels;
        int numberOfSuperpixels;

        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud;
        bool pointCloudAvailable;

        Eigen::MatrixXd* features;

    };
}
```

Source:

```
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/features/integral_image_normal.h>
#include "Tools.h"
#include "SuperpixelFeatures.h"

SuperpixelFeatures::SuperpixelFeatures(const cv::Mat &image, int** labels) {

    this->image = new cv::Mat();
    int channels = image.channels();

    assert(channels == 1 || channels == 3);

    if (channels == 1) {
        image.convertTo(*this->image, CV_8UC1);
    }
    else if (channels == 3) {
        image.convertTo(*this->image, CV_8UC3);
        cv::cvtColor(*this->image, *this->image, SEEDS_REVISED_OPENCV_BGR2Lab, 3);
    }

    this->height = image.rows;
    this->width = image.cols;

    this->pointCloudAvailable = false;

    // Copy labels.
    this->labels = new int*[this->height];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
        this->labels[i] = new int[this->width];

        for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
            this->labels[i][j] = labels[i][j];
        }
    }

    this->numberOfSuperpixels = seeds_revised::tools::Integrity::countSuperpixels(this->labels, this->height, this->width);
    seeds_revised::tools::Integrity::relabel(this->labels, this->height, this->width);

    this->features = new Eigen::MatrixXd(this->numberOfSuperpixels, 1);

    // Initialize first column with labels.
    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {
        (*this->features)(label, 0) = label;
    }
}

SuperpixelFeatures::SuperpixelFeatures(const cv::Mat &image, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud, int** labels) {
    assert(image.rows == (int) pointCloud->height);
    assert(image.cols == (int) pointCloud->width);

    this->image = new cv::Mat();
    int channels = image.channels();

    assert(channels == 1 || channels == 3);

    if (channels == 1) {
        image.convertTo(*this->image, CV_8UC1);
    }
    else if (channels == 3) {
        image.convertTo(*this->image, CV_8UC3);
        cv::cvtColor(*this->image, *this->image, SEEDS_REVISED_OPENCV_BGR2Lab, 3);
    }

    this->pointCloud = pointCloud;
    this->height = pointCloud->height;
    this->width = pointCloud->width;
    this->pointCloudAvailable = true;

    // Copy labels.
    this->labels = new int*[this->height];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
        this->labels[i] = new int[this->width];

        for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
            this->labels[i][j] = labels[i][j];
        }
    }

    this->numberOfSuperpixels = seeds_revised::tools::Integrity::countSuperpixels(this->labels, this->height, this->width);
    seeds_revised::tools::Integrity::relabel(this->labels, this->height, this->width);

    this->features = new Eigen::MatrixXd(this->numberOfSuperpixels, 1);

    // Initialize first column with labels.
    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {
        (*this->features)(label, 0) = label;
    }
}

SuperpixelFeatures::~SuperpixelFeatures() {
    delete this->image;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
        delete[] this->labels[i];
    }

    delete[] this->labels;
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addMeanBGRColor() {
    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + 3);

    double meanB = 0;
    double meanG = 0;
    double meanR = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {

        meanB = 0;
        meanG = 0;
        meanR = 0;
        count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
                if (this->labels[i][j] == label) {
                    meanB += this->image->at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
                    meanG += this->image->at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
                    meanR += this->image->at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }

        (*this->features)(label, cols) = meanB/count;
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 1) = meanG/count;
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 2) = meanR/count;
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols + 2);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addMean3DPosition() {
    assert(this->pointCloudAvailable);

    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + 3);

    double meanX = 0;
    double meanY = 0;
    double meanZ = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {

        meanX = 0;
        meanY = 0;
        meanZ = 0;
        count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
                if (this->labels[i][j] == label) {
                    meanX += (*this->pointCloud)(j, i).x;
                    meanY += (*this->pointCloud)(j, i).y;
                    meanZ += (*this->pointCloud)(j, i).z;
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }

        (*this->features)(label, cols) = meanX/count;
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 1) = meanY/count;
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 2) = meanZ/count;
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols + 2);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addMean2DPosition() {

    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + 2);

    double meanX = 0;
    double meanY = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {

        meanX = 0;
        meanY = 0;
        count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
                if (this->labels[i][j] == label) {
                    meanX += j;
                    meanY += i;
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }

        (*this->features)(label, cols) = meanX/count;
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 1) = meanY/count;
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols + 1);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addMeanNormal() {
    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + 3);

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {
        std::vector<int> indices;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
                if (this->labels[i][j] == label) {
                    indices.push_back(i*cols + j);
                }
            }
        }

        Eigen::Vector4f superpixelCentroid;
        Eigen::Matrix3f superpixelCovariance;
        Eigen::Vector3f superpixelNormal;

        pcl::compute3DCentroid(*pointCloud, indices, superpixelCentroid);
        pcl::computeCovarianceMatrix(*pointCloud, indices, superpixelCentroid, superpixelCovariance);
        Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> superpixelEigenValues(superpixelCovariance);
        superpixelNormal = superpixelEigenValues.eigenvectors().col(0);

        (*this->features)(label, cols) = superpixelNormal(0);
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 1) = superpixelNormal(1);
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 2) = superpixelNormal(2);
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols + 2);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addArea() {
    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + 1);

    int area = 0;
    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {

        area = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
                if (this->labels[i][j] == label) {
                    ++area;
                }
            }
        }

        (*this->features)(label, cols) = area;
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addSuperpixelStatistics() {
    assert(this->pointCloudAvailable);

    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + 3);

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {
        std::vector<int> indices;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
                if (this->labels[i][j] == label) {
                    indices.push_back(i*cols + j);
                }
            }
        }

        Eigen::Vector4f superpixelCentroid;
        Eigen::Matrix3f superpixelCovariance;
        Eigen::Vector3f superpixelNormal;

        pcl::compute3DCentroid(*pointCloud, indices, superpixelCentroid);
        pcl::computeCovarianceMatrix(*pointCloud, indices, superpixelCentroid, superpixelCovariance);
        Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> superpixelEigenValues(superpixelCovariance);



        // Point-ness:
        (*this->features)(label, cols) = superpixelEigenValues.eigenvalues()(0);
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 1) = superpixelEigenValues.eigenvalues()(2) - superpixelEigenValues.eigenvalues()(1);
        (*this->features)(label, cols + 2) = superpixelEigenValues.eigenvalues()(1) - superpixelEigenValues.eigenvalues()(0);
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols + 2);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addColorHistogram(int bins) {
    assert(bins > 0 && bins < 10);

    int histogramSize = std::pow(bins, 3);
    int cols = this->features->cols();
    this->features->resize(this->numberOfSuperpixels, cols + histogramSize);

    int* normalization = new int[this->numberOfSuperpixels];
    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {
        normalization[label] = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < histogramSize; ++k) {
            (*this->features)(label, cols + k) = 0;
        }
    }


    int denominator = ceil(256./((double) bins));
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
            int bin = this->image->at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0]/denominator + bins*(this->image->at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1]/denominator) + bins*bins*(this->image->at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2]/denominator);
            ++(*this->features)(this->labels[i][j], cols + bin);
            ++normalization[this->labels[i][j]];
        }  
    }

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {
        for (int k = 0; k < histogramSize; ++k) {
            (*this->features)(label, cols + k) /= normalization[label];
        }
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(cols, cols + histogramSize);
}

Eigen::Vector2i SuperpixelFeatures::addGroundTruth(int** labels) {
    int numberOfLabels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
            if (labels[i][j] > numberOfLabels) {
                numberOfLabels = labels[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Remember that zero may be a label as well.
    numberOfLabels = numberOfLabels + 1;

    Eigen::MatrixXi intersection(this->numberOfSuperpixels, numberOfLabels);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->width; ++j) {
            assert(this->labels[i][j] < this->numberOfSuperpixels);
            assert(labels[i][j] < numberOfLabels);

            ++intersection(this->labels[i][j], labels[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int label = 0; label < this->numberOfSuperpixels; ++label) {

        int maxIntersection = 0;
        int maxGTLabel = 0;
        for (int gtLabel = 0; gtLabel < numberOfLabels; ++gtLabel) {
            if (intersection(label, gtLabel) > maxIntersection) {
                maxIntersection = intersection(label, gtLabel);
                maxGTLabel = gtLabel;
            }
        }

        (*this->features)(label, 0) = maxGTLabel;
    }

    return Eigen::Vector2i(0, 0);
}

int SuperpixelFeatures::getFeatureDimension() const {
    return this->features->cols();
}

Eigen::MatrixXd* SuperpixelFeatures::getFeatures() const {
    return this->features;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For python I'd recommend using `fast_slic` which is WICKED fast despite only using a CPU. As for accessing the individual segments try reading over Adrian Rosebrock's tutorial on PyImageSearch and using a bounding box algorithm to find the specific roi you're interested in. If your work needs only the image itself and no zero padding, then you can try `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d` along with a condition to only retain image patches that do not have zeros across the channels.